# How to save Firebase Data into an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database that is modeled as such:

```
: users
    : some-random-id-1
        - username:"user1"
        - email:"email1@gmail.com"
    : some-random-id-2
        - username:"user2"
        - email:"email2@gmail.com"
```

I am trying to iterate through all the users in the dictionary of data and append the username into a list in the file to be used for other purposes. I created a string array (userslist) variable and in viewdidload(), I wrote the following code below:

```
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let dataDict = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let x = dataDict["users"] as! NSDictionary
        print(x)
        print("--------")
        for user in x{
            let y = user.value as? [String: String]
            let z = y!["username"]
            print(z)
            self.userslist.append(z!)
            print(self.userslist)
            print("NEXT")
        }
    })
    print(self.userslist)
```

Inside the brackets of the snapshot, when I print self.userslist, I can see that each element is getting added, but when I print it a final time outside of the brackets, it shows it as an empty array. I think that the elements are only appended in the scope of those brackets so I cant access the filled array anywhere else. How do I get around this so I can use the data I appended?

Comment: the very last line, that bottom print statement would get printed before the print statement inside the brackets. That last line runs immediately after ref?. observe... It would get printed before everything inside the brackets runs

Answer (score 1):

you are using **print(self.userslist)** outside the observer and Firebase run in Async Mode

So, if you make use of **breakpoints** you will notice that

`print(self.userslist)` is Called before the control reach onside the **Database handler** ,

data is **getting fetched** you need to load your views inside that handler using **Dispatch main queue**

```
    ref?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dataDict = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            let x = dataDict["users"] as! NSDictionary
            print(x)
            print("--------")
            for user in x{
                let y = user.value as? [String: String]
                let z = y!["username"]
                print(z)
                self.userslist.append(z!)
                print(self.userslist)
                print("NEXT")
            }
            /// Here is your data
            print(self.userslist)
        })
 /// Called before Handler execution
 print(self.userslist)
```

Comment: Did this answer helped you , if yes you can accept this answer and close this thread else you can post solution for others and accept that , thanks